# How to get the path of the data storage in iPhone simulator 5.1?

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, osx-lion

I've read from other answers that it can be found in this path `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Media/DCIM/100APPLE` but when I checked in my mac, there is no `iPhone Simulator` inside `Application Support`..

I am using mac lion, xcode 4.3 with iphone sim 5.1

Comment: Have you tried to search for it in the terminal? Open the terminal and put this in: `ls Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator`. What does the terminal answer?

Comment: Already found it, sorry I checked on the wrong Library folder. I never thought there is another Library folder on lion. :)

Comment: Make this an answer and accept it to help others with the same problem.

Comment: Can't answer my own question but the solution I found was,

Finder->Go->(hold Alt)->Library->Application Support->iPhone Simulator->5.1(the version of the simulator)

I was looking for the photos so I continued to Media->DCIM->100APPLE

btw, you need to hold alt so the Library will show

Answer (score 2):

There is some issue. Actually your folder may be hidden so you need to first make visible it.

If you open up `Terminal` (Applications > Utilities) and type the following:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
```

Then Go to Folder and USERS/YourUserName/Library/Application Support "

Like this :  `/Users/nirav/Library/Application Support`

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

you can find data  told by @Anshul Jain or do that NSLog your path in iPhone app while saving your files in your app then you  can get complete path and then copy that path and paste in gotofolder option hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can found it here....

```
 /Users/"your main directory"/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator
```